# List disappearing when clicking icon

Tags: html, css, dom

**PROBLEM'S ROOT:** I've got a list when clicking an icon on a web application. It's working fine but when it has many elements, it goes 'above' the screen and I can't see it. This is the upper section of the screen:

[image]

I am almost sure the solution would be a tiny CSS attribute, but can't find which one.

Here is the list:

```
<div class="fg-menu-container ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 450px; bottom: 35px; top: auto; right: auto; left: 0px; display: block;">

<ul id="documentlist" class="fg-menu ui-corner-all" role="menu" aria-activedescendant="active-menuitem" aria-labelledby="documentListButton">

        AAA<li role="menuitem"><a href="_#" data-cid="c67" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img title="Edit Attachment" alt="Edit Attachment" src="/_dev/images_/Attachment16.png">test</a></li>

        AAA<li role="menuitem"><a href="_#" data-cid="c68" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img title="Edit Attachment" alt="Edit Attachment" src="/_dev/images_/Attachment16.png">test</a></li>

       ...

        AAA<li role="menuitem"><a href="_#" data-cid="c91" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img title="Edit Attachment" alt="Edit Attachment" src="/_dev/images_/Attachment16.png">test</a></li>


        <li role="menuitem">
            <hr class="top-border-item ui-state-default">
            CCCC<a href="_#" id="uploadDocumentLink" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img title="Attach a document" alt="Attach a document" src="/_dev/images_/AddAttachment16.png"> Attach a document</a>
        </li>


</ul></div>
```

Here are the CSS classes involved:

```
.fg-menu-container { 
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:-999px; 
    padding: .4em;  
    overflow: hidden; 
    z-index: 999
}

.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.ui-widget-content { padding: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; }

.ui-corner-all {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.fg-menu a:active { 
    float:left; 
    width:92%; 
    padding:.3em 3%; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    outline: 0 !important; 
}
```

Comment: you should remove `top:auto` from `style` attribute of `<div class="fg-menu-container ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"` if you're going to set the `position` property to `absolute`. makes no sense.

Comment: @OzguzBar Do you think this is causing the issue?

Comment: eighter this or `bottom: 35px;` which again does not look reasonable. I'd eighter try using `top:0` or removing `bottom:35px`

Comment: and i think you need to post the css and html definitions for the icon panel also.

Answer (score 1):

Did u try this?

> .fg-menu-container ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all{
>       width: 450px;
>       bottom: 35px;
>       top: 0;
>       right: auto;
>       left: 0px;
>       display: block;
>       overflow: auto;
>   }

The desciption doesnt really tell what exactly is the issue here..!!
If you could help understand the same thing more, it would be of great help.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's not working. What do you mean with "The desciption doesnt really tell what exactly is the issue here..!!"? I think that is more than clear; when I click the icon, the list appears above the screen as you can see in the image, so I am not able to see the list. Please read carefully the description before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `style` attribute from div element and use it like this:

```
<div class="fg-menu-container ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Then you can customize the class like this

```
.fg-menu-container { 
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
    padding: .4em;  
    overflow: auto; 
    z-index: 999;
    width:450px;
    height:100px;
}
```

While I don't know why you used `left:-999px;`, you can include that in the css definition if you're not having any problem in displaying the div properly. Giving the div a fixed height and setting `overflow` property to auto can be a good idea.

There are bunch of things which are mixed up in the css. You're setting `absolute` value for `position` attribute. Then you're using

```
top: 0;
top: auto;
bottom: 35px;
```

again all mixed up.

If you're trying to display the contents in an absolute positioned div, the css above should get the job done. Where or how you wish to position it is a different matter and highly related to parent element, which you have not clarified.

> You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set
>   the location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next
>   parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no
>   such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element
>   itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

When you use `bottom:35px` for the div element which happens to be in another relative div (like the icon panel you're using), it will adjust itself according to the position of that panel. Your complete html and css definitions are missing, but I'd go for `top:0` instead of that.